# How to implement a copy constructor / assignment operator for a class that has a self-referential pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I'm not quite sure if it's possible to implement a copy constructor/assignment operator, so that if I wanted this class to be equal to another bags instance, it would replace itself with that instance.

I've already tried the general assignment operator implementation (checking for self-referencing etc.).

```
template <typename T>
class bags {
public:
  bags(const bag<T>& b) {

  }

  bags<T>& operator=(bags<T> const &b) {

  }

  private:
  bags<T> * self;
}

template <typename T>
class apples : public bags<T> {
public:
  void test () {
    self = new bags<T>; // this will invoke assignment operator
  }

private:
  bags<T> * self;
}
```

Bags is a base class to apples (derived). I expect to be able to have bags contain itself and apples.

Comment: As written, your question and your code do not make much sense. Also copying a pointer does not invoke the copy constructor of the class but only copy the pointer value. If an object contain a pointer to an object of its own type, then essentially, you have a single linked list. At that point, do you want deep copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to use

```
bags<T> * self;
```

There is always the language provided `this`. If you must use `self` for some reason, make it a member function.

```
bags<T> const* self() const
{
   return this;
}

bags<T>* self()
{
   return this;
}
```

Another option is to use function local variables.

```
bags<T> const* self = this;  // In const member functions.
bags<T>* self = this;        // In non-const member functions.
```

Comment: So if I want to set an instance of bags to another instance. I'd simply do *this = *(b.self) in the copy constructor? Will the current instance have all of the data from b?

Comment: @LinearM, most of the time yes. The answer is no if (a) Your class allocates and deallocates memory and (b) You have not implemented a custom `operator=` function. Please follow [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) to make sure that that's not a problem.